# Chrome 61: avoid PWA opening _blank links in Custom Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

The latest version of Chrome for Android (61) introduced a 'feature': PWA's open links with `target="_blank` (or `window.open()`) in a Chrome Custom Tab instead of just launching Chrome and opening a new tab for the user.

But what if I don't want that? Is there some way I can prevent this from happening (as the dev of the site) or a setting somewhere (for users)?

Comment: Sorry if I am resurrecting the dead. Have you ever found an answer to your question? I am trying to do something similar but with not much luck.

Comment: Nope, no solution that I know of as of yet..

Comment: I thought setting `target="_blank"` was supposed to handle that, but as you've noted, it doesn't.  I've filed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1171894 to track it.

Comment: Starred it! Thanks!